# How do I listen for mouse button hold

Tags: cocos2d-js

I'm using Cocos2d-JS and need to find a way to listen for a mouse button hold. It seems limited in that there's only onMousemove, onMouseDown, and onMouseUp. All of those only get fired once. How do I use them to detect when a mouse button is being held down? I can't just use onMouseDown since that's being used to perform an action if the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following solution for this. You can have a counter. `onMouseDown` will launch a method that will increment the counter via `setInterval` and check whether the counter reached the target value. If the value is reached, it will trigger whatever you want to be triggered by mouse button hold. `onMouseUp` will wipe off the interval counter. Here is the simplified code. Assuming these to be methods of an object.

```
onMouseDown: function() {
    this.launchTimer();
},

launchTimer: function() {
   //Timer will update every 100ms
   this.counter = 0;
   this.timer = setInterval(() => {

       //Assume our target value is 1s or 1000ms
       if (this.counter === 1000) {
           //Launch your function here
           this.onMouseHold();
           this.clearTimer();
         } else {
           this.counter += 100;
         }
       }, 100);

    this.timer();
},

clearTimer: function() {
   this.counter = 0;
   clearInterval(this.timer);
},

onMouseUp: function() {
   this.clearTimer();
}
```